# Surface Curvature in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a built-in way to get the mean, normal, gaussian, or principal curvatures of a vertex on a mesh in three.js?

I know there are already functions that compute face and vertex normals, but I'm not sure how these normals relate to the local curvatures at those vertices.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is 'no'.

Comment: In that case is there a method of getting the mean normal at a vertex? Right now if I use the vertex normal helper for example, I get multiple normals on each vertex, one for each neighboring face.

Comment: If you call `geometry.computeVertexNormals()` prior to rendering, do you still show multiple normals at each vertex?

Comment: Yes, I am currently calling that function within an stl loader before adding the renderer. Although if I compute the normals after everything has loaded, it returns one normal per vertex. I'm trying to estimate convexity or concavity at any vertex in the mesh. In curved regions the face normals diverge more. With that in mind, can you recommend any approach for getting the curvature at a vertex?

Comment: What happens if you call `geometry.mergeVertices()` prior to calling `geometry.computeVertexNormals()`?

Comment: I have not studied the literature on the topic of estimating curvature of a mesh. See https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=mesh+curvature.

Comment: Merging the vertices before computing the normals fixed the problem with multiple normals on each vertex. I think I will use the logic in the edges helper using threshold angles between face normals to approximate surface curvature. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It appears your geometry is "triangle soup". You are not sharing vertices, which is required in three.js to determine adjacency information. Your suggested approach may suffice, but my preference would be to avoid reinventing the wheel since this problem has been solved before.